# Why in dart in my Cubit LoadedState does code not execute and get skipped?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a LoadedState that runs in my cubit perfectly, until I try and filter the data it is about to display, as it doesn't run that code at all! It skips all the for loop and goes straight to return.

```
 else if (state is LoadedState) {
            var matches = state.matches;

            for (var i = widget.selectedFilters.length; i < widget.selectedFilters.length; i++) {
              print("111");
              if (matches[i].leagueNumber == widget.selectedFilters[i]) {
                print("222");
                matches.removeAt(i);
              }
            }
            print("333");

            return Container(
```

The output in the logs is just 333.

Does anybody know why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to your `for` loop. You're starting the index from `widget.selectedFilters.length` already. It won't be like this. I assume that you need to start it from `0`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < widget.selectedFilters.length; i++) {
         print("111");
         if (matches[i].leagueNumber == widget.selectedFilters[i]) {
            print("222")
            matches.removeAt(i);
          }
      }
```